# How can I call an angular $scope function from a separate js file?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I am debugging someone else's software. It uses Angular 1.5.9, which I am not very familiar with and I have not been able to find an answer to my questions.

1. I would like to call a $scope function that exists in a separate controller, from another controller in a separate js file.
2. The broadcast statement below throws an error and I am unsure as to why? "TypeError: Cannot read property '$broadcast' of null"

Here is the code:

**CONTROLLER 1**:

```
app.controller('FilterController', function ($scope, $filter, 
$uibModalInstance, errorService, dataService, values) {
    $scope.sortByColumn = function () {
      var data = { 'editorID': $scope.editorID(), 'filter': 
      dataService.data.objFilterColumns };

      dataService.getData('UpdateFilter', data).then(function (response) {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

        //I WANT TO CALL THE SCOPE 'reloadData' FUNCTION HERE
        $scope.$emit('reloadData', data);

        //this broadcast statement was already there but it throws error 
        $scope.$parent.$broadcast('sortbyColumn', $scope.userFilters, $scope.column.strColumnName, $scope.orderDir, dataService.data.objFilterColumns);

    });
  });
```

**CONTROLLER 2**:

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", [
"$scope",
"$http",
"$uibModal",
"$log",
"$location",
"$window",
"dataService",
"errorService",
"lookupService"
, function ($scope, $http, $uibModal, $log, $location, $window, dataService, errorService, lookupService) {
    $scope.loadPage = function (data, message, removeFilter, byColumn, 
 orderDir) {
    //I want to call this function from the other controller 
  }

  $scope.$on("reloadData", function () {
     $scope.loadPage();
  });

  $scope.$on("sortbyColumn", function (event, filters, column, orderDir, filter) {
    //some code
  });
}]);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Define global javascript variables in your app.js file for each controller, something like given.

```
var PayRateScope, ManageResourceScope, sequenceScopePA;
```

2. Now in your controller, at end of defination of app.controller method, assign $scope to respective gloabal scope variable. 
   for ex.

```
// Payrare Controller
app.controller('PayRateAdminController', function ($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout) {
   // your code and functions
  PayRateScope = $scope;
});
```

```
//ManageResource Contoller
app.controller('ManageResourceController', function ($scope, $compile, $http, $timeout) {
   // your code and functions
  ManageResourceScope = $scope;
});
```

3. Now you will be able to access functions inside respective controller using it global variable in any external js like,

```
PayRateScope.FunctionName();
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked and this seems like the most straightforward way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

You can use service:

```
app.service('someService', function () {
    this.loadPage = function (data, message, removeFilter, byColumn, orderDir) {
        //...
    };
});
```

And inject it into the controllers:

**Controller1:**

```
app.controller('FilterController',["$scope","someService" */andOther/*, function ($scope, someService) {
    $scope.sortByColumn = function () {
      var data = { 'editorID': $scope.editorID(), 'filter': 
      dataService.data.objFilterColumns };

      dataService.getData('UpdateFilter', data).then(function (response) {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');

       someService.loadPage(...parameters);


  });
```

**Controller2:**

```
 app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope','someService' ,function($scope, someService){
    $scope.loadPage = someService.loadPage(data, message, removeFilter, byColumn, 
 orderDir);

}]);
```

From AngularJS docmentation:

AngularJS services are substitutable objects that are wired together using dependency injection (DI). You can use services to organize and share code across your app.

AngularJS services are:

Lazily instantiated – AngularJS only instantiates a service when an application component depends on it.
Singletons – Each component dependent on a service gets a reference to the single instance generated by the service factory.

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, you need to understand the different between $broadcast(), $emit() and $on()

`$broadcast()` - sends an even downwards from parent to child controllers.

`$emit()` - sends an event upwards from the current controller to all of its parent controllers

`$on` - An event raised by $broadcast() and $emit() can be handled by wiring an event handler using $on()

`$scope.$parent` - mean you access parent controller scope.This will help you to access variable and method in parent controller.

Looks like this.
[image]
Hope this will make you clear on these terms.

Comment: Thanks, how do I determine which controller is the parent and which is the child?

Comment: Try this plugin.
http://ng-inspector.org/